# in node, using Q, make 2 functions work in parallel but wait only for the first one to fulfill its promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, workflow, promise, q

In my environment I use node +q (which I'm not a great expert of), so the main argument is: promises.

I have a function that needs to make 2 operations in parallel, a very long one and a very short one.

```js
var parallelWrapper = function(input) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var fastPromise = fastComputation()
    .then(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data)
      },
      function(err) {
        deferred.reject(err)
      });
  // of course this one below is not going to work properly
  var slowPromise = slowComputation()
    .then(function(data) {
      makeSomething();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      makeSomethingElse();
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  Q.all([fastPromise, slowPromise]);

  retrun deferred.promise;
}
```

this function will be called in a chain of promises, because the result of the first operation is needed, while the result of the 2nd is not.

```js
var myLongChainOfFunctions = function() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  firstFunction(someParams)
    .then(secondFunction)
    .then(thirdFunction)
    /*...*/
    .then(parallelWrapper)
    .then(someFunction(data){
      /* Do Something with the data returned only by fastPromise*/
    }
    /*...*/
    .then(lastFunction)
    .fail(doSomething)

  return deferred.promise;

}
```

What I would like to do is to make them go in parallel but to resolve as soon as fastPromise is done, so that the chained promises can move forward, but obviously at some point in the future I would also like slowPromise to finish.
So I just would like slowPromise to live its life, do what it has to do and not care too much if succeed or fails.

My impression is that it's not possible with Q, but maybe there's a solution I'm not spotting.

Comment: Your `Q.all()` call doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your `Deferred` is also completely useless; you can use the promise directly.

Comment: It sounds like you want to return two separate promises.

Comment: ok, maybe I should have clarified at the beginning: this is just an example, is not supposed to run or whatever. My question is: can we run 2 functions in parallel but wait for just one of them before moving forward, while the other asynchronously finish its task, since it won't affect the workflow anyhow?

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? An async function will not magically stop just because you don't observe its result.  However, you need to decide how you want to handle errors.

Comment: that's the point, I don't want it to stop. I want it to finish. What the workflow is not interested in, is the result. I don't care if it ends up in error or if it finish with success. so:
* fastFunction works and fulfill, the chain moves on
* slowFunction works and fulfill, the chain already moves, we didn't wait for it. is it possible like this?

Comment: Yes; that will just work.  Did you try it?

Comment: @SLaks I edited the code a bit to see if it become more clear. Is quite likely that I haven't explained myself good enough and for that I'm sorry, so I hope you see what I mean now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done so:

```
var parallelWrapper = function(input) {

  var fastPromise = fastComputation();

  var slowPromise = slowComputation()
    .then(function(data) {
      return makeSomething();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      return makeSomethingElse();
    }).catch(console.error);

  return Q([fastPromise, slowPromise]).all();
}
```

And second example somthing like this:

```
var myLongChainOfFunctions = function() {

  return firstFunction(someParams)
    .then(secondFunction)
    .then(thirdFunction)
    /*...*/
    .then(parallelWrapper)
    /*...*/
    .then(lastFunction)
    .catch(doSomethingWithError)

}
```

ok, you can do this like:

```
var parallelWrapper = function(input) { 
      slowComputation()
        .then(function(data) {
          return makeSomething();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          return makeSomethingElse();
        }).catch(console.error);

      return fastComputation();
    }
```

Comment: Yes but this way parallelWrapper would not fulfill and the chain would not move on before both fast and slow computation are ready, right? I would like it to move on soon as fastComputation is ready

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it doesn't seems to work the way I wish it does: I edited the code of the question, the main problem is that function in the 'then' chained after parallelWrapper won't have any input parameter but undefined, while I wish it could have the result of fastComputation as input parameter

Comment: In input parametr you will have returned data from fastComputation(). If you hava undefined you have problem in fastComputation(), i can see this function body?

Comment: ok, so your solution is implemented [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PhTFASV5) and it produces the following output on step 4:
_4. should have fastComputation result: undefined_

Comment: You must return parallelWrapper Promise with data in 63 line.

Comment: And i recommend you use q-fs

Comment: So, as later I figured out that was the problem, the function has to be returned, so thank you very much! and thank you also for the advise on q-fs, but the IO functions in this case are just examples